# Python - Print items in list with neither commas nor apostrophes

Tags: python

Minimal working example of my code:

```
# Create output data file
out_data_file = open('output_file','w')
out_data_file.write("# Header \n")
out_data_file.close()

list1 = [1,3,4,5,12,6,2,35,74,6,2]

# Open file to append
with open('output_file', "a") as f:
    f.write('Text'+'  '+str(['%d' % item for item in list1]))
```

which gives me an `output_file` that looks like:

```
# Header 
Text  ['1', '3', '4', '5', '12', '6', '2', '35', '74', '6', '2']
```

I want the output to look like this instead:

```
# Header 
Text  1 3 4 5 12 6 2 35 74 6 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `str()` the individual elements instead of the whole list...?

Comment: What you are doing is using a list comprehension to build a list, after which you convert the list to a string. This results in the string including the square brackets and the commas. As both Fredrik and Mark suggest, you need to use join to join to items in the list together in a string. Join lets you specify the separators to use in between the list items.

Comment: Just for some variety: `reduce(lambda x, y: '%s %s' % (x,y), [1,3,4,5,12,6,2,35,74,6,2])` -> `'1 3 4 5 12 6 2 35 74 6 2'`

Comment: Looks like CSV to me:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Use

In [10]: list1 = [1,3,4,5,12,6,2,35,74,6,2]

In [11]: " ".join(map(str, list1))
Out[11]: '1 3 4 5 12 6 2 35 74 6 2'
```

...or in your case:

```
f.write('Text' + ' ' + " ".join(map(str, list1)))
```

Comment: Using `map` looks cleaner than my answer, but Guido himself prefers list comprehensions and generator expressions - see http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html

Comment: I agree, and I upvoted yours, but it's not every day I get higher score than the mighty Mark Ransom so I'm quite happy :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
f.write('Text'+'  '+' '.join('%d' % item for item in list1))
```

Or, since it looks like you are OK with the default conversion of an integer to string:

```
f.write('Text'+'  '+' '.join(str(item) for item in list1))
```

Comment: I have no idea which answer is better but since the other one got more votes I marked it as the correct one. Peer pressure :) Oh and thank you very much!